# AutoMapper Nested Mapping not working. Here is the config and code :

Tags: c#, automapper

Followed the steps mentioned in Automapper wiki to configure nested mapping with complex objects. but not working :

```
public class Student
    {
        public int ID{get;set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Standard { get; set; }
        public List<string> Course { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string  MotherName{ get; set; }
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
        public int TestCondition { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }

    }

  public class Address
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }
```

DTO :

```
public class StudentDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Standard { get; set; }
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string BG { get; set; }
        public int TestCondition { get; set; }
        public AddressDTO AddressDTO { get; set; }

    }
 public class AddressDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }
```

Configuration :

```
public class AutoMapperProfileConfig : Profile
    {

        public AutoMapperProfileConfig()
        {

            CreateMap<Student, StudentDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.DOB, opt=>opt.Ignore())
                                            .ForMember(x=>x.BG,opt=>opt.MapFrom(y=>y.BloodGroup))/*.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Name = "After MAP")*/
                                            .ForMember(x=>x.TestCondition, opt=>opt.Condition(src => (src.TestCondition >= 100))
                                            );
CreateMap<Address, AddressDTO>();
```

Execution :

```
Student student = new Student();
            Address add = new Address();
            add.Line1 = "abcd";
            student.Address = add;
            var studentLite = Mapper.Map<StudentDTO>(student);
```

Although studentDTO is getting mapped properly the AddressDTO is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mapping `Student.Address` to `StudentDTO.AddressDTO`. As the name of your target property has changed, AutoMapper doesn't know what to do with it. If you changed your propertyname in `StudentDTO` from `AddressDTO` into `Address`, Automapper should be able pick it up and map it.

An alternative solution would of course be to instruct AutoMapper explicitly to map `Student.Address` to `StudentDTO.AddressDTO`.

Comment: I have used CreateMap<Address, AddressDTO>(); for the mapping. Check the config section. Still gives null. same name works i have tried that already. I am trying out something like this from automapper wiki : [link]https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings

Comment: that just creates the map from class Address to AddressDTO. I'm talking about your property names. AutoMapper only automatically maps properties that are named identical. Yours are not identical, therefore you have to tell AutoMapper how to map them.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek, Thanks man. It helped. Why did not I think of this explanation on my own.